# Running R notebook from command line

Tags: r, command-line

Ok, I'm trying to run this script through a batch file in Windows (server 2016), but it just starts to push out lineshifts and dots to the output screen:

"c:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.1\bin\rscript.exe" C:\projects\r\HentTsmReport.R

The script works like a charm in RStudio, it reads a html file (a TSM backup report) and transforms the content into a data frame, then it saves one of the html tables as a csv-file.

Why do I just get a gunk of nothing on the screen instead of an output to the csv when running through rscript.exe?

My goal is to run this script through a scheduled task each day to keep a history of the backup status in a table to keep track of failed backups through tivoli.

This is the script in the R-file:

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
#library(tidyverse)
library(rlist)
theurl <- getURL("file://\\\\chill\\um\\backupreport20181029.htm",.opts = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE) )
tables <- readHTMLTable(theurl)
tables <- list.clean(tables, fun = is.null, recursive = FALSE)
n.rows <- unlist(lapply(tables, function(t) dim(t)[1]))
head(tables) 
test <- tables[5] # select table number 5
write.csv(test, file = "c:\\temp\\backupreport.csv")
```

Comment: rscript.exe does not load all of the packages that r.exe (or RStudio) automatically loads. I would check to see if any of your functions are affected. For instance, `head()` is part of the `utils` package. Can you create a script to output which libraries are loaded by rscript.exe and see if you are missing any?

Comment: I'm hoping you might just be able to add `library(utils)` to the top of your code. But I'm not sure if you are seeing missing library issues or something else.

Comment: What makes this an r notebook?